# This version (v8.31) of natbib is stricter in its formatting requirements for bibitem entries than the previous version used at arXiv (v7.1)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, overleaf, arxiv

Please guide how to fix? This is for NAACL conference format and works on overleaf. I am not sure why it breaks in arXiv:
Here is a link to git repo of the code https://github.com/monajalal/WiNLP2018

```
TeX log appears below

[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2016 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <best.png>   is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <naaclhlt2018.sty>   is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <main.tex>   is of type 'PDFLATEX'.
[verbose]: <spacy.png>  is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <acl_natbib.bst> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/2268283/ && pdflatex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/authblk.sty) (./naaclhlt2018.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))
Conference Style for NAACL-HLT 2018
(/texlive/2016/texmf-local/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty

This is natbib version 8.31 
*************************************************************
!!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! 

This version (v8.31) of natbib is stricter in its formatting
requirements for bibitem entries than the previous version
used at arXiv (v7.1).

If your submission encounters a problem see

http://arXiv.org/help/faq/texlive

and the natbib documentation at 

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/

for explanation and adjust your submission accordingly.
The arXiv team.
*************************************************************

)) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/diagbox/diagbox.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/p2e-pdftex.def))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/soul/soul.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.79 \begin
{document}
? 
! Emergency stop.
... 

l.79 \begin
{document}
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/2268283/ && pdflatex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/authblk.sty) (./naaclhlt2018.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))
Conference Style for NAACL-HLT 2018
(/texlive/2016/texmf-local/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty

This is natbib version 8.31 
*************************************************************
!!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! !!WARNING!! 

This version (v8.31) of natbib is stricter in its formatting
requirements for bibitem entries than the previous version
used at arXiv (v7.1).

If your submission encounters a problem see

http://arXiv.org/help/faq/texlive

and the natbib documentation at 

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/

for explanation and adjust your submission accordingly.
The arXiv team.
*************************************************************

)) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/diagbox/diagbox.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/p2e-pdftex.def))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/soul/soul.sty)
No file main.aux.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1pcr.fd)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `MohammadZhKiMa15' on page 1 undefined on inpu
t line 87.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `FarzindarIn15' on page 1 undefined on input l
ine 88.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `SamekiGeMaGuBe16' on page 1 undefined on inpu
t line 89.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `SamekiGeMaGuBe16' on page 1 undefined on inpu
t line 89.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `SamekiGeMaGuBe16' on page 1 undefined on inpu
t line 92.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `PintoOlAl16' on page 1 undefined on input lin
e 120.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Bird06' on page 1 undefined on input line 120
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ManningSuBaFiBeMc14' on page 1 undefined on i
nput line 120.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `RitterClMaEt11' on page 1 undefined on input 
line 120.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `JurafskyMa08' on page 1 undefined on input li
ne 122.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `JurafskyMa08' on page 1 undefined on input li
ne 122.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `McCallumFrPe00' on page 1 undefined on input 
line 122.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `SuttonMc12' on page 1 undefined on input line
122.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `WangHuZhZh16' on page 1 undefined on input li
ne 122.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ZhangLi17' on page 1 undefined on input line 
122.

[1{/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

Package natbib Warning: Citation `ThelwallBuPa10' on page 2 undefined on input 
line 125.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Thelwall17' on page 2 undefined on input line
125.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `aylien' on page 2 undefined on input line 128
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `msftnlp' on page 2 undefined on input line 12
8.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `watsonnlu' on page 2 undefined on input line 
128.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `gcnlp' on page 2 undefined on input line 128.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `rosette' on page 2 undefined on input line 12
8.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Thelwall17' on page 2 undefined on input line
128.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `RitterClMaEt11' on page 2 undefined on input 
line 128.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `spaCy' on page 2 undefined on input line 128.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `KhashabiSaZhre18' on page 2 undefined on inpu
t line 128.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `FiGrMa05' on page 2 undefined on input line 1
28.


Underfull \hbox (badness 1024) in paragraph at lines 128--129
\OT1/ptm/m/n/10.95 licly ac-ces-si-ble com-mer-cial APIs for the task

Package natbib Warning: Citation `SamekiGeMaGuBe16' on page 2 undefined on inpu
t line 135.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `mTurk' on page 2 undefined on input line 135.


<spacy.png, id=16, 981.6675pt x 83.31125pt> <use spacy.png>
<best.png, id=18, 912.40875pt x 158.5925pt> <use best.png>

Package natbib Warning: Citation `SamekiGeMaGuBe16' on page 2 undefined on inpu
t line 192.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `tensi' on page 2 undefined on input line 206.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `gcnlp' on page 2 undefined on input line 206.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `rosette' on page 2 undefined on input line 20
6.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `gcnlp' on page 2 undefined on input line 206.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `spaCy' on page 2 undefined on input line 206.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `StanfordNER' on page 2 undefined on input lin
e 206.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `CogCompNLP' on page 2 undefined on input line
206.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `twitternlp11' on page 2 undefined on input li
ne 206.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `rosette' on page 2 undefined on input line 20
6.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `WeischedelPaMaHo13' on page 2 undefined on in
put line 211.


Underfull \hbox (badness 1584) in paragraph at lines 211--212
\OT1/ptm/m/n/10.95 with the de-fault val-ues of the model. Fur-

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig1' on page 2 undefined on input line 221.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `FarzindarIn15' on page 2 undefined on input l
ine 222.
```

Comment: I don't think the warning you cite in the title is the problem. It is only a warning after all. There definitely is an error with `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.` It seems you (or other packages you load) load `hyperref` twice with conflicting options. Don't do that. Load it only once.

Comment: I am not loading it twice though. I have checked.

Comment: @moewe I added all the files here can you please have a look at the git repo? https://github.com/monajalal/WiNLP2018

Comment: Mhh, the document works fine if I compile it on my machine. Not sure what changes the arXiv applies. Maybe it is enough to remove the `hyperref` option from `\usepackage[hyperref]{naaclhlt2018}` for the arXiv submission.

Answer (score 1):

The log here doesn't show the complete error message. The `option clash for hyperref` error is arXiv's ad hoc application of hyperref to all submissions (unless explicitly disabled by the user), and not related to the natbib issue that is in question.

I also see that this submission has expired, so if you're still having trouble, please upload the files to arXiv again, and ask for help via help@arxiv.org.

Answer (score 0):

The `hyperref` package should be loaded *after* any other package. In this case, the natbib is just a warning and should not cause compilation errors.